# htaccess URL system: Server showing the file instead of controller page if exists

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to set up a simple `example/url/system` thing using `htaccess`, which I haven't done for many many years admittedly, and all was working fine until a file actually exists, at which point it no longer redirects to `index.php?var=String`, it simply displays `String.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?vfirst=$1&vsecond=$2&vthird=$3    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?vfirst=$1&vsecond=$2    [NC,L]   
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?vfirst=$1    [NC,L]
```

My example is `/users/edit-profile/`. Before I had created `users/edit-profile.php`, the server would take me to `index.php` and display my `404 page` (as well as debug confirming vfirst - vthird were set and read correctly) - however as soon as I created a blank `edit-profile.php`, the blank page is all that comes up instead of `index.php`. I have the PHP covered to include `users/edit-profile.php` if it exists and is the URL chosen, but I don't think its getting that far.

`Regex/htaccess` was never my thing but even I think it's looking light and I must be missing a line that basically tells it to ignore whether the file exists, capture the variables and go to `index.php`. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question correctly, but I would try to answer as far as I understand.

So, if you need do display some page, when a non-existent page is called, then try to use this script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . somepage.php [L]
```

If you need to do something else, then please let us know, and maybe me or someone else would provide necessary information.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The htaccess I've got (with the code) if I access say, /test/example/ itll work and display index.php?vfirst=test&vsecond=example (which I then use to include test/example.php using PHP) - however as soon as I actually create test/example.php it no longer shows index.php, it just tries to open the file itself. So my htaccess works as long as the file DOESN'T exist, as soon as it does the URL system gets ignored and the blank page is shown on its own, instead of included in the index.php page. Hope thats a little clearer! Thank you though